# I've tried different things but can't fix: Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.4

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

I keep getting the

Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.

Error in:

- CATALOG -> Products

Doing the:

*TRUNCATE ui_bookmark;*

**Is a very temporary fix and as soon as I change the filter to anything else again, the problem comes back.**

I have done the following:

1. Hosting increased the PHP timeout limit from 60 to 300 seconds.
2. I have increased the session limit in Store > Settings > Configuration to some astronomical number.

When I look at what Error comes up in:

```
/public_html/var/log/debug.log
```

It is this:

```
main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively.
```

I am not finding any solutions when I google this Error. **How to fix this?**

---

UPDATED:

There are more Errors in the log now:

```
[2023-03-10T20:21:00.269788+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:25.317662+00:00] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.134758+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.135201+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.135481+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.135675+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.135765+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.135885+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.135971+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.136049+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar.container.paylater' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.136241+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.136397+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.136571+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T20:42:55.136655+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.571613+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.572077+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.572356+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.572528+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.572619+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.573216+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.573470+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.573606+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.573790+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.573879+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.574036+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.574125+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []
[2023-03-10T21:00:11.574285+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product_view_custom_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []

main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/CsrfValidator.php:105)"} []

main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://MYWEBSITE.com/admin","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BACKEND_MAINMENU"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2023-03-10T21:20:11.297081+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://MYWEBSITE.com/admin","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["PB_EDITOR_CONFIG","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []

cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://MYWEBSITE/admin/system_config/save/key/3159abf01bafc885fd5d32e2e04c5564431f2c9432744dd4ebafa256a625acd9/section/customer/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["config_scopes","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []


main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://MYWEBSITE/admin/admin/order_shipment/save/order_id/11/key/98e4758b479dfc700cb32b9a253cc7b03c4d5e25ab81d9e4921e6b0e744c325b/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_c_p_254","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2023-03-10T21:38:16.027186+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://MYWEBSITE/admin/admin/order_shipment/save/order_id/11/key/98e4758b479dfc700cb32b9a253cc7b03c4d5e25ab81d9e4921e6b0e744c325b/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_c_p_255","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2023-03-10T21:38:16.027338+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://MYWEBSITE/admin/admin/order_shipment/save/order_id/11/key/98e4758b479dfc700cb32b9a253cc7b03c4d5e25ab81d9e4921e6b0e744c325b/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_c_p_254","cat_c_p_255"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2023-03-10T21:38:16.028311+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://MYWEBSITE/admin/admin/order_shipment/save/order_id/11/key/98e4758b479dfc700cb32b9a253cc7b03c4d5e25ab81d9e4921e6b0e744c325b/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p_1045","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2023-03-10T21:38:16.029354+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://MYWEBSITE/admin/admin/order_shipment/save/order_id/11/key/98e4758b479dfc700cb32b9a253cc7b03c4d5e25ab81d9e4921e6b0e744c325b/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p_1045"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
```

---

**UPDATED:**

I've deleted the debug.log file, then ran the following:

TRUNCATE mage_ui_bookmark;

Then, I go to:

- Catalog - Products

This page loads but when I put in 16 (as in - I want to go to page 16 when viewing 20 products per page) - it always creates the following Error in debug.log:

```
main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

And gives the:

```
Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.
```

Error in the Magento Admin panel.

I have done the same with system.log (clear it before running the TRUNCATE command) and the only Error it generates after I try to go to page 16 of products listing is as follows:

```
main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

**I wonder if it has to do with incorrect data/illegal characters in some of the product's details. One of my colleagues was putting spaces, - ' " % in many products in different fields. I have just Exported the products from Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1 and imported them into Magento 2.4.5-p1.**

*The thing is that I can go clicking the Next arrow from 1 to 15 with no problems (after running the TRUNCATE command) but as soon as I hit page 16 of product listings, that's when the Error comes up.*

---

I have a total of 2265 products. When I set the filter to show 20 products per page (in Catalog - Products) - it shows there are a total of 114 pages. When I go through from page 1 and keep clicking the right arrow to go through all pages up to 114, these are the only pages where the Error comes up on:

```
16
26
106
```

**Does this indicate a problem with a product/products on those pages and if so, how to identify and fix this?**

---

**UPDATED** on April 11th, 2023:

I've tried to follow instructions from @Zahid Hussain Magento

I've gone into:

- Catalog - Products - right click and Inspect - then go to one of the pages that throws up the Error = page 16 and this is what it records in Console:

  JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 3.3.2
  DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://pfjibkklgpfcfdlhijfglamdnkjnpdeg/performance-now.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
  DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://pfjibkklgpfcfdlhijfglamdnkjnpdeg/index.esm.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
  DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ecmgkhgjmodembdmiimbacpjgcdimiek/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
  DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://eidlalmjabcfgiimceghbmhjmhkpjclj/jquery.qtip.min.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
  jquery.js:10109

  GET https://MYWEBSITE.com/new/mui/index/render/?namespace=product_listing&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=16&search=&keywordUpdated=false&sorting%5Bfield%5D=entity_id&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=asc&isAjax=true 500
  send @

**There is nothing in the Network other than:**

checkout-data-resolver.js is listed at the top.

If I close that and click on:

namespace=product_listing&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=16&search=&keywordUpdated=false&sorting%5Bfield%5D=entity_id&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=asc&isAjax=true

It shows the following:

```
ValueError: imagecolorsforindex(): Argument #2 ($color) is out of range in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:347
Stack trace:
#0 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php(347): imagecolorsforindex(Object(GdImage), 254)
#1 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php(288): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->applyTransparency(Object(GdImage), 254)
#2 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php(432): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->fillBackgroundColor(Object(GdImage))
#3 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2/Interceptor.php(59): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->resize(75, 75)
#4 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image.php(115): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2\Interceptor->resize(75, 75)
#5 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php(520): Magento\Framework\Image->resize(75, 75)
#6 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(479): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image->resize()
#7 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(539): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->applyScheduledActions()
#8 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Thumbnail.php(67): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->getUrl()
#9 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(396): Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Thumbnail->prepareDataSource(Array)
#10 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(393): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Thumbnail))
#11 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(393): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor))
#12 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(251): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#13 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/ContentType/Json.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->getDataSourceData(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#14 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(158): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContentType\Json->render(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing), 'templates/listi...')
#15 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(91): Magento\Ui\Component\AbstractComponent->render()
#16 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
#17 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
#18 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#19 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#20 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
#21 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#24 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(145): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#28 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor))
#31 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#33 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#35 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#37 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#38 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#39 {main}
```

---

**The fix suggested by @cnbandicoot (below) to switch to ImageMagick mostly worked.** *I still get the Error every once in a while on the list of products. I also get the following Error randomly when I open products:*

**A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.**

Comment: Is there anything inside var/log/system.log file?

Comment: @dudzio - I have posted the contents of the system.log file and started a bounty for this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Allysin,

This error happens due to these possibilities issues:
1) Custom extensions/third party themes ( custom attributes and fields )
2) Data issue, Reimport all products while removing special characters mostly like these ( space, /,\,*,$,%,&,!,',",? *).

NOTE: when you go to catalog -> products inspect -> network and see response, preview) if you face spinner/loader first remove it and again reload product grid page.

let me know if you still face this.

or share also products in zip so I can check at my self.


Thank you.
Zahid H

Comment: @Zahid Hussain Magento - I will check the CSV file again. Just to make sure - the characters you mentioned ( space, /,\,*,$,%,&,!,',",? * ) - are we saying these should NOT be present in the SKU and URL key fields? Are there any other fields (such as  Product Name) where they could be causing problems also? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Allysin, 
Yes,you have to delete from product name and description two.

Try this method also:
Try import only 100 products with skus, type,  attribute (default), product name etc and and test what happens?  if it works import in chunks and test every time, Also can you tell me do you have custom attributes in products grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last update, there is an [related PR](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/36679) for this error in Magento repository.

This error is caused because some image types are not recognized correctly with PHP GD Library.

To solve this issue, you can use ImageMagick instead of GD2.

Go to `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Image Processing Settings` and update the value from `PHP GD2` to `ImageMagick`.

> (Alternatively you can run `bin/magento config:set dev/image/default_adapter IMAGEMAGICK`)

Then run in console the command `bin/magento catalog:image:resize` (after run `bin/magento cache:flush`).

If you can't use ImageMagick you can add the code from the related PR to your project with a composer patch to include this fix.

Comment: Wow - that worked! That's amazing! I hope this post will help other people facing the same problem also. Are there any negative side effects to using ImageMagick instead of GD2? Thank you for helping on this.